# Drawing a common horizontal line for multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want that all the three subplots have a common horizontal line keeping the distance between the subplots unchanged. Basically I just want to fill the spaces between three horizontal lines to create one large horizontal line. How can this be done?
Here is the figure
[image]

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis=['HE','BBHE','BHEPL','DOTHE','RSIHE','QDHE','RSWHE']
y_drive=[0.480,0.478,0.638,0.508,0.475,0.587,0.846]
y_stare=[0.759,0.766,0.856,0.659,0.777,0.767,0.865]
y_chase=[0.482,0.515,0.809,0.763,0.520,0.802,0.802]

x=np.array(np.arange(0,1.30,0.2))
x=np.arange(0,7)
width=1

fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3)=plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True,sharex=True)    #returns subplot axes or object
ax1.bar(x,y_drive,width,color=['r','g','b','c','m','y','k'],alpha=0.80)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',bottom=False,left=False,labelbottom=False)
ax1.set_xlabel('DRIVE')
ax1.set_ylim(0,1)

ax2.bar(x,y_stare,width,color=['r','g','b','c','m','y','k'],alpha=0.80)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',bottom=False,left=False,labelbottom=False)
ax2.set_xlabel('STARE')

ax3.bar(x,y_chase,width,color=['r','g','b','c','m','y','k'],alpha=0.80)
ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax3.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',bottom=False,left=False,labelbottom=False)
ax3.set_xlabel('CHASE')

plt.show()
```

Comment: The same way as you have create each subplot, have you try it?

Comment: I am not getting it! please help.

Comment: Did you try from this awnser : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933905/matplotlib-adding-subplots-to-a-subplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without using multiple plots. The trick is to use a custom x-values and width.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()    #returns subplot axes or object

x=np.arange(-0.75, 0.8, 0.25)
width=1/4.

ax1.bar(x,y_drive,width,color=['r','g','b','c','m','y','k'],alpha=0.80)
ax1.bar(x+2,y_stare,width,color=['r','g','b','c','m','y','k'],alpha=0.80)
ax1.bar(x+4,y_chase,width,color=['r','g','b','c','m','y','k'],alpha=0.80)

ax1.set_xticks(range(0, 6, 2))
ax1.set_xticklabels(['DRIVE', 'STARE', 'CHASE'])
ax1.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',bottom=False,left=False,labelbottom=True)

ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a simple query, what if I want to add legend corresponding to each color. How can this be done?

Comment: @Navdeep : Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974928/how-to-create-custom-legend-in-matplotlib-based-on-the-value-of-the-barplot) answer and search for other similar posts using "custom legends in bar chart matplotlib"